# Do MSIs contain a checksum?

Tags: deployment, installation, wix, windows-installer, checksum

I'm writing a utility to deploy some MSIs on remote machines. Do MSI files contain a built-in checksum that will be checked when they are run, or do I need to write something to check that they have been downloaded OK? The MSIs will be created with WiX if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digitally sign the MSI  and you'll know if it's valid or not.